# DATEDIFF in Group by causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am posting it a new question as previous question has changed a bit. I am using this query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,servicestart,CheckinTime) abondendedTime FROM Location L INNER JOIN
     Interaction I
     ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY L.Id, L.Description,DATEDIFF(SECOND,servicestart,CheckinTime)
```

and it is returning 700 rows where as I don't need this part

DATEDIFF(SECOND,servicestart,CheckinTime) in GROUP BY but If I don't put it in GROUP BY, I get error:

```
Column 'Interaction.ServiceStart' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I want this result set

http://prntscr.com/f993xe

I need to do these calculations.

http://prntscr.com/f995dk

I have done this part

```
SELECT L.Id,
       L.Description AS 'Location',
       COUNT(L.Id) Interactions,
       SUM(CASE WHEN I.ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Abandoned,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN I.ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) *100)/COUNT(I.Id) AbandonedPercent
       FROM Location L
       INNER JOIN Interaction I
       ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
       GROUP BY L.Id,L.Description
```

and need to calculate

```
Average Abandon Time,Members,Repeat Members,Repeat Visits,Repeat/Interaction,Average Wait,Average Service
```

Above first query is for Average Abandon Time

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT L.Id, L.Description,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, servicestart, CheckinTime)) as abondendedTime
FROM Location L INNER JOIN
     Interaction I
     ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY L.Id, L.Description;
```

Unlike your previous question, the column in the `WHERE` is different from the column used for the `DATEDIFF()`.